# Stored procedures (delete invoice)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a stored procedure for deleting an invoice from the db.

Three tables is affected:

- INVOICE - Contains InvoiceID, Date and CustomerID (fk)
- INVOICELINE - Contains InvoicelineID, InvoiceID (fk), ArticleID (fk), Quantity, Price and Discount
- ARTICLE - Contains articles with Articlename, Quantity, Price and Discount.

  This is what I want:

  1. You call the SP with one argument, InvoiceID
  2. The number of an item on an invoice line is added back to the Article table to the quantity of that item.
  3. All the invoice lines on the invoice is deleted
  4. The invoice is deleted

Below is what I have so far, which is a SP for deleting an invoice line. I want this SP to be called from a SP called DeleteInvoice. The problem is that I can't figure out how that SP should be designed to be able to get this work, for example how do I loop through the invoice lines on an invoice? Would be glad if anyone could help out here.

The SP for deleting an invoice line (should be called from the SP that's deleting an invoice, the number of times as there are invoice lines):

```
@InvoiceID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Articleid int, @Quantity int
    SELECT @Articleid = ArticleID, @Quantity=Quantity
    FROM InvoiceLine
    WHERE InvoiceID=@InvoiceID

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE Article SET Quantity=Quantity+@Quantity
            WHERE ArtikelID=@Articleid;

            DELETE FROM InvoiceLine
            WHERE InvoiceLineID=@InvoiceLineID;
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR ('Couldn't delete the invoice line!',16,1)
    END CATCH   
END
```

Comment: Loopy thinking won't get you far in SQL.  SQL is designed to deal with set operations, e.g. updating all of the line items in an invoice.  It's a very different hammer from most procedural languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you intentionally chopped off the `CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE` line before your `@InvoiceID` declaration. You can do this with three statements in a transaction - no need for multiple procedures or looping:

```
@InvoiceID int
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- This reclaims inventory to the Article table
    WITH R AS (
      SELECT ArticleID, SUM(Quantity) ReclaimedQuantity
      FROM InvoiceLine
      WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
      GROUP BY ArticleID
    )
    UPDATE Article
    SET Quantity = Quantity + R.ReclaimedQuantity
    FROM Article INNER JOIN
         R ON Article.ArticleID = R.ArticleID;

    -- Removes invoice line items
    DELETE FROM InvoiceLine
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    -- Removes the invoice header item
    DELETE FROM Invoice
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
  END CATCH
END
```